# Image rendering issues when running Roblox under Wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine, opengl

I Use [Grapejuice](https://gitlab.com/brinkervii/grapejuice) to run Roblox on Wine/Linux (specifically Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). And recently, out of a blue got a rendering issues that causes only DirectX 11 to work as my renderer, OpenGL comes with a black Screen, And Vulkan just crashes with a white screen.

I would be fine with this but DirectX 11 runs Horribly, most of the time not even above 20 fps. And from my previous tests a while ago OpenGL runs best for me.

So what I’m asking for is a solution that lets me use OpenGL with no real issues. As far as I know Roblox did not get any update, this started happening in about the afternoon of June 2nd.

I currently don’t know how to get any logs of these things, if you do, tell me and I’ll gladly provide them.

Comment: Which version of Wine?

Answer (score -2):

This can help you. https://libredd.it/r/wine_gaming/comments/v4sxml/roblox_through_grapejuice_black_screen_issue/

A lot of people are having the same issue today for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Thanks a lot! possibly roblox got an update?